# Dynamic Webservice with Json in grails

Tags: json, web-services, grails

I want to implement a dynamic webservice in grails, where the user can define the data that should come dynamically. So the user can for example say, the data contains a person with firstname and lastname.

In XML I could create a xsd to check, if the data that comes to the service is correct.

What can I do in grails to check, if the json data is correct? Is there something like a xsd for json? Would it be an option to convert the json to xml and check it against an xsd?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails can run pretty much any Java library easily so all you need to do is find a Java implementation of a JSON validating mechanism. An example would be http://json-schema.org/ which defines a JSON validation schema and offers 2 different Java implementations. Note that is is good practice to include external libraries by a repository reference as opposed to downloading the file and copying it into your project folder.

This should get you going, for more details please open another question and present more code and what you've tried so far, as well as the Grails version you are using.